# How do I open all windows when clicking the icon in Ubuntu dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

When I have for example two Nautilus windows open, and I click the icon in the dock on the left it shows me the preview of the two windows. I then need make a decision which one I need before it shows the window to me.

Can I make it work so that when I click the icon it simply shows all the open windows? All tips are welcome!

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 / GNOME.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the click-action on Ubuntu Dock icons. Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

Now if you click on an application icon with multiple open windows, it will switch between minimising and restoring all windows.

Comment: To reset back to the default, run `gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action`

Answer (score 5):

Run in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-previews'
```

The whole action list is  [here](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/blob/master/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.gschema.xml)